# How can I automate updating NuGet packages and building a solution in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, visual-studio-macros

Here is my workflow.

1. Open Package Manager Console
2. Update-Package
3. Build Solution
4. Check into Plastic Source Control
5. Build in Teamcity

The problem is I keep forgetting to do #3! This is key because it updates my config files prior to check in. How can I set up a one click method to do 1-3? Or some kind of command line macro.

Answer (score 0):

Have it defined in the 'Build Steps' in TeamCity instead. (under Configuration Settings)

Typically have one build step that would have

Runner Type: Command Line
Step Name: nuget restore (or anything you desire)
Run: Custom Script
Custom script: nuget.exe restore

If you add the necessary steps to TeamCity you wouldn't need to build them before you push into your source control.